# No output when run function

Tags: r, csv

New to R and to programming, I reviewed all the possible threads on SO on this Coursera assignment but couldn't figure out what the issue was. I know this function can be optimized using lapply and much more, but I would like to know why this particular function does not work. I felt like some questions on this function slightly irritated some users. To be honest, I reviewed the relevant posts on that and I don't see what I can do about this particular bug.

```
    pollutantmean <- function (directory, pollutant, id) {
  #Create the data frame with the data from the 332 files

  files <- list.files(getwd())
  df <- data.frame()
  id <- 1:332

  for (i in 1:length(id)) {df <- rbind(df, read.csv(files[i]))

  if (pollutant=="nitrate"){ 

    #Create a subset for nitrate values of df
    df_nitrate <- df[df$ID==id[i], "nitrate"] 

    #Take mean of df_nitrate
    mean (df_nitrate, na.rm = TRUE)

    } else {
    #Create a subset for sulfate values of df
    df_sulfate <- df[df$ID==id[i],"sulfate"] 

   #Take mean of df_sulfate
     mean(df_sulfate, na.rm = TRUE)
     }
  }
}
```

For those of you who have not heard of this assignment function: I have 332 csv files(named 001.csv, 002.csv and so on) in my working directory. The task is to get all of them in one data frame and to be able to call the mean of a column of a file (given by "id" variable that corresponds to that file) or across multiple files (some examples of function and output can be found [here](https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/rprog%2Fdoc%2Fpollutantmean-demo.html))

I tried to call traceback or debug functions to situate the problem, but to no avail:

```
pollutantmean(getwd(), "nitrate", 23)
> traceback()
No traceback available 
> debug(pollutantmean)
>
```

The OS is Windows 10.

Any suggestions or comments are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What is the error message?

Comment: At `df[df$ID==id[i], "nitrate"]`, filtering by id seems redundant since you are loading CSV files of the specified `id`.  I think you need to compute the mean outside the for loop, after you loaded all CSV files.

Comment: @MaxPD There is no message, that's the thing.

Comment: @KotaMori id is for specific files.Each file has a nitrate and sulfate column. When I limit the loop to rbind as you suggested it deals only with the first file, however.

Comment: Since you have `df$ID==id[i]`, it returns the mean of only `i`.  If you want to compute mean across multiple files, remove this part

Comment: @KotaMori Oh, I see. The trouble is that id is also a variable of my function. When specified by user it must return a mean of a column across many files, so I thought this subsetting reflected this need. Now, if I remove that condition, it will give me the mean of all the columns of all the files which is not what I expect. Still, I tried your suggestion on the function and it produced an incorrect mean, just as I expected. Maybe I should ponder a bit more over this subsetting issue. Thanks for your answers, though!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop is wrapped around your if `block`. R functions will not return a value while in a loop (unless you use the `return` function, which is not what you want to do here).

```
  pollutantmean <- function (directory, pollutant, id) {
  #Create the data frame with the data from the 332 files

  files <- list.files(getwd())
  df <- data.frame()
  id <- 1:332

  for (i in 1:length(id)) {df <- rbind(df, read.csv(files[i]))
  # close for loop HERE
  }

  if (pollutant=="nitrate"){ 

    #Create a subset for nitrate values of df
    df_nitrate <- df[df$ID==id[i], "nitrate"] 

    #Take mean of df_nitrate
    mean (df_nitrate, na.rm = TRUE)

    } else {
    #Create a subset for sulfate values of df
    df_sulfate <- df[df$ID==id[i],"sulfate"] 

   #Take mean of df_sulfate
     mean(df_sulfate, na.rm = TRUE)
     }
  # not HERE
  #}
}
```

Comment: In fact, that was my initial take, but that returns only the means from the first file. But now at least I know why there was no output. Thank you, Adam.